# How to get rows of unique pairs of ids?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table of user pairs:

[image: table]

How could I select the rows so I have pairs once? For instance if I have 1-2, I don't need 2-1. So this is the desired output:

```
1 | 2
4 | 11
5 | 6
7 | 8
```

Maybe this is a case where the query gets too complex and it's better to just get the results of the image, and work on the result set in the application.

I use PostgreSQL, if that helps to optimize the query.

Comment: if it is guaranteed that (1,2) and (2,1) both appear, you can add an `AND user_id <= pair_id`

Comment: @HansZ works great! although just using the < symbol seems to be enough, can you write an answer please?

Comment: `<=` is for the edge case (9,9), if you have to deal with that. You should accept @GordonLinoff 's answer, though, it's more correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
select distinct least(user_id, pair_id), greatest(user_id, pair_id)
from userpairs;
```

This method has the possibility of returning a pair that doesn't actually exist in the table (for instance, if "(9,3)" appears and there is no "(3,9)").  If you want only actual pairs in the table, you can do:

```
select user_id, pair_id
from userpairs up1
where user_id <= pair_id or
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_pairs up2
                  where up2.user_id = up1.pair_id and up2.pair_id = up1.user_id
                 );
```

If there is the possibility of duplicates in the original data, then you will want `select distinct` here as well.  Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: @HansZ: I don't think your edit improves Gordon's answer. Neither `DISTINCT` nor `<=` are needed. Fooled me into posting another answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The edit doesn't do anything if you assume (9,9) doesn't happen and (1,2) doesn't happen more than once.

Comment: @HansZ: Don't think it's *wrong* (or I would have rolled back). It's just a *change* that we generally don't edit into other peoples' answers. It makes the query slower. And the distinct step potentially changes the order of rows. You should have written your own answer with your first idea.

Comment: +1 very nice answer, useful even when it's necessary that (9,3) appears and (3,9) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no completely identical duplicates to deal with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pair p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   pair
   WHERE  (user_id, pair_id) = (p.pair_id, p.user_id)
   AND    pair_id < user_id
   )
```